# I've been trying to install home-brew with Ruby on a Mac with OSX 10.13- No Joy

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, homebrew

I've been trying to install home-brew with Ruby on a Mac with OSX 10.13. Based on some suggestions here, I used XCode to make a `brew_install.rb` script with the home-brew script contents.

However, running it with ruby produces:

```
brew_install.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input 
HOMEBREW_CACHE = "#\{ENV["HOME"]\}/Library/Caches/Homebrew".freeze\
```

Any idea what this is about?

Comment: Your script has a `syntax error`. That means Ruby cannot parse your script properly. How does your script look like?

Comment: single command should be:                                                                       /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Comment: The link there is the script I have tried to use without success.

Answer (score 2):

To install Homebrew use this single-line command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

This came straight from the [Homebrew web page](https://brew.sh).

Comment: That's actually where I started- it returns "Illegal variable name."  The script I have been trying to use, and the one I did the process above with, is the one that link points to, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install